# File_exists() не работает

Tags: php, файлы

Есть 200 с лишним php-файлов, созданных с помощью fopen(). Ни один из них не детектирует file_exists(). Что с этим делать?

Comment: Убедиться, что на вход `file_exists()` поступают немного неверные значения и подкорректировать их.

Comment: Уверен, что верные.

Comment: А код, который там написан, предлагается угадать? Может там просто неверно написано условие.

Comment: @Burack Habain, окей, если прочитать файл с этого верного пути, данные попадут в переменную? Только без хардкода.

Comment: Ничего не открывается, ничего не передаётся. В папке лежит файл 1.php. Делаю fopen(папка/1.php) -- он мне создаёт в этой же папке другой файл 1.php! В одной папке два файла с одинаковыми названиями и расширениями... Через редактор открываются оба...

Comment: > Ничего не открывается, ничего не передаётся.

говорю же, проблема в путях

> В одной папке два файла с одинаковыми названиями и расширениями...

похоже на невидимые символы в названии, strlen должен подсказать реальную длину имени файла в байтах

Comment: Или буковки похожие, но одни латиницей, другие кириллицей, например.

Comment: Кстати, пробелов случайно нет после расширения? Самый дурацкий и незаметный косяк.

Answer (score 1):

1. Без кода - верного ответа никто не даст.
2. Скорее всего проблема в пути, который Вы пишите в file_exists()
3. Может быть, при создании файлов, Вы их не закрывали fclose();
4. Проблема так же может быть в кириллице.